# SceneKit: Rotate node but define target angles

Tags: swift, scenekit

EDIT: I have solved the problem and will post the solution in the next couple of days.

---

I'm building 3D achievements similar to Apple's Activity app.

I've already loaded my 3D model (a scene with a single node), can show it, and can tap on it to apply a rotational force:

```
@objc func objectTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = gesture.location(in: scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(tapLocation, options: [:])

    if let tappedNode = (hitResults.first { $0.node === badgeNode })?.node {
        let pos = Float(tapLocation.x) - tappedNode.boundingBox.max.x
        let tappedVector = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: pos, z: 0, w: 0.1)
        tappedNode.physicsBody?.applyTorque(tappedVector,
                                            asImpulse: true)
    }
}
```

This works fine. Now to the tricky part:

I want the node to rotate until it either shows its front or backside (like in the Activity app), where it then should stop. It should stop naturally, which means it can *overshoot* a bit and then return.

To describe it with pictures - here I am holding the node in this position...

[image]

...and if I let go of the node, it will rotate to show the front side, which includes a little bit of overshooting. This is the ending position:

[image]

Since I'm quite new to SceneKit, I have troubles figuring out how to achieve this effect. It seems like I can achieve that by using SceneKit objects like **gravity fields**, without having to calculate a whole lot of stuff by myself, or at least that's what I'm hoping for.

I don't necessarily ask for a full solution, I basically just need a point in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get the nodes orientation (node.eulerAngles).  After the tapped event, you should be able to check the rotation, do some math and force the rotation where you want it.